External Monitors Not Detected via DisplayLink Dock on Dell Latitude 7650 with i915 and EVDI Drivers - Ubuntu 22.04
My Machine is a Dell Latitude 7650 running Ubuntu 22.04, with a DisplayLink-based Dell D6000 dock to connect external monitors. I cannot get the external monitors to work, even though the system detects the dock and the DisplayLink driver is active. Here's as detailed rundown of what I’ve tried and the outputs I’ve seen as I can give:
Laptop Model: Dell Latitude 7650
DisplayLink Dock: Dell D6000
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-49-generic
Graphics Driver: Attempting to use the i915 driver for integrated Intel GPU alongside the DisplayLink EVDI driver.

I Installed the DisplayLink Driver from Synaptics.
evdi/1.14.7, 6.8.0-49-generic, x86_64: installed
Set Kernel Boot Parameters: Modified /etc/default/grub to include:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... simpledrm.modeset=0 i915.force_probe=7d45"
Confirmed Active Modules: Verified that the i915 and evdi drivers are loaded:

lsmod | grep -E 'i915|drm|gpu'
i915                 4292608  0
drm_buddy              20480  1 i915
drm_display_helper    237568  1 i915
ttm                   110592  1 i915
evdi                   73728  1


DisplayLink Service Status: Ensured the DisplayLink service is running:

sudo systemctl status displaylink-driver.service
● displaylink-driver.service - DisplayLink Driver Service
   Active: active (running)

Some other things that might help you understand this situation:
xrandr Output: Running xrandr --listproviders shows the providers:
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x40 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x99 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 2: id: 0x62 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting

However, attempts to set providers with:
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 0x99 0x40
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 0x62 0x40
xrandr --auto

give these errors:
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
The outputs are recognized - /sys/class/drm Information: ls /sys/class/drm/ card0  card0-Unknown-1  card1  card1-DVI-I-1  card2  card2-DVI-I-2 
The connector statuses are correctly reported when the monitors are plugged in or unpluggged.Despite xrandr correctly detecting the providers, the external monitors don’t appear to be configured. The DisplayLink dock is detected, and the DisplayLink/EVDI driver is loaded, but the external monitors do not display. Attempts to configure outputs via xrandr fail with errors, and the external monitors remain unrecognized by the X server.
the only other error that might help is this;
evdi: [I] (card2) Cannot find any crtc or sizes [drm] Initialized i915 and evdi modules 
From the kernel logs.
Thanks for any help!
